# error while trying to add data to database with seeder

Tags: php, laravel

This my schema in my migration file. I am using [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) package to create nested categories

[image: database schema]

When I try to insert the data to my database with `php artisan db:seed --class=ShopSeeder` I get this error.

[image: error]

Database seeder file

[image: database\seeders\ShopSeeder.php]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to add your code as text, not as a picture so it is easier for us to reproduce. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `Shop::factory()->create()` in your seeder instead of `Shop::create()`. I would create a shop factory if you haven't already done so.

The error says that you are passing an array of children, but the framework expects a string, so probably the column is of type *varchar*.